# HOWTO: Manipulate Back Arrow Icon and Button on Navigation Bar (Xamarin Forms / Android)

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am attempting to change the size of the back arrow in the navigation bar.

Using information from [this](https://www.liudeyun.net/xamarin-custom-navbar-icon-text/) article, I have added the following code:

```
protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page view, bool animated)
{
    var result = base.OnPushAsync(view, animated);

    var activity = (Activity) Context;
    var toolbar = activity.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

    if (toolbar != null)
    {
        if (toolbar.NavigationIcon != null)
        {
            if (toolbar.NavigationIcon is DrawerArrowDrawable navigationIcon)
            {
                // Code goes here?
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

If this is indeed the correct *path*, what code goes in the area marked by the comment "Code goes here?"?

*** UPDATE ***

I realized that what I am trying to figure out was not exactly described in my original question.

More specifically, when I mentioned that I am trying to resize the navigation bar back arrow, what I am really trying to do is to resize the *button* that the icon appears on.

For example, if I shrink the height of the navigation bar using code like the following:

```
On<Android>().SetBarHeight(100);
```

The button that the icon appears on will be clipped.

Ultimately, what I am trying to accomplish is resizing the icon *AND* the button that the icon appears on. I have already figured out how to do the former.

Answer (score 0):

> I am attempting to change the size of the back arrow in the navigation bar.

If you want to change size of the back button in the navigation bar, you can get new icon from Drawable in resource for  toolbar.NavigationIcon.

```
public class NavigationPageRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer
{
    public AppCompToolbar toolbar;
    public Activity context;

    protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page view, bool animated)
    {
        var retVal = base.OnPushAsync(view, animated);

        context = (Activity)Forms.Context;
        toolbar = context.FindViewById<AppCompToolbar>(Droid.Resource.Id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            if (toolbar.NavigationIcon != null)
            {
                if (toolbar.NavigationIcon is DrawerArrowDrawable navigationIcon)
                {
                    // Code goes here?
                    toolbar.NavigationIcon = Android.Support.V7.Content.Res.AppCompatResources.GetDrawable(context, Resource.Drawable.back);
                    toolbar.Title = "Back";
                }

            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Here is the sample you can take a look:

https://github.com/hachi1030-Allen/XamarinCustomNavBar

Comment: The sample you referenced allows you to change the icon. While I could certainly swap out the default icon with a smaller one of my own, this still does not resize the button the icon is on. I realized that my original question was not the most specific so I have updated it with additional detail.

Comment: @Jason, You want to change navigation bar icon size, am I right? If yes, there are different hdpi folder in resource folder, so you add different size icon in different hdpi, you can choose size icon that you want.

Comment: I have already figured out how to change the image. I am trying to change the size of the button the image appears on. If I resize the navigation bar's height to be smaller, the button gets clipped.

Comment: @Jason, Do you solved your issue now? Anything update sharing?

Answer (score 0):

`<NavigationPage.TitleView>` will help you out there. This is a `XAML` approach.

Example:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
     <StackLayout>
     ....
     </StackLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Using this approach you will be able to set **HeightRequest** and **WidthRequest** of whatever element you place inside the **StackLayout** and whatever else you want to amend.

Also, note that if you are having icon size problems it may be worth looking into whether or not your drawable/ icons are the right size for the right resolution.

Comment: Unless I have missed something, the `NavigationPage.TItleView` concept will allow you to replace the portion of the navigation bar that includes the page title. I am trying to resize the back button on the navigation bar that is displayed when there is more than one page on the navigation stack.

Comment: I understand that, however, as all the **back button** does is technically pop a page off of the navigation stack, you can simply use a back button img of your choice (or the same as androids/iOS) and call `PopAsync()` or whatever your mvvm framework offers. I have did this in a previous application.

Comment: I have already figured out how to change the button image using one of my own...that is not the issue. When I use a smaller image, the size of the image button remains the same and gets clipped when I resize the toolbar. I am trying to figure out how to resize this image button.